# Comparing a date between mutiple lines SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

first off, sorry for my bad English, I'm a French Canadian.

I'm trying to compare one datetime between mutliple start datetime and end datetime, but my query doesn't work and SQL Server gives me this error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
SELECT V.SampleTime,
       V.OrderNo,
       V.VNCCode,
       V.VNCDescription,
       V.NrOfOccurences,
       V.Comment
FROM AV_RPT_FQC_Visual V
INNER JOIN AV_RPT_PO_Header H
ON H.OrderNo=V.OrderNo
WHERE H.LinkUp IN (SELECT * FROM @iLinkupID) 
AND (V.NrOfOccurences > 0 or V.VNCCode = '00.00.00')
-- This part doesn't work --> AND SampleTime between (Select ShiftStart From @shifts) and (Select ShiftEnd From @shifts)
ORDER BY SampleTime, VNCCode
```

Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: What's the data in @shift? Looks like you have more than 1 record in it.

Comment: Usually you would want to use a column from the query in the subquery to limit the ShfitStart value to the corresponding data.

Comment: @EricZ The shifts table contains the start time and the end time of every shift since the beginning of 2013. I need to find a every sampletimes that are between one of the shift in the shifts table. Thanks!

Comment: @user2957784, could you please update your questions with some sample data and desire output? I'm still confused.

Comment: @EricZ Sorry if I'm not clear.
I have multiple shifts (Example: StartTime: 11/11/2013 22:59:00 and EndTime: 13/12/2013 23:59:59) and a Sample Time (Example: 12/11/2013 05:12:32) and I want to know in which specific shift my sample time is. If I have 50 000 shifts, I want to know if my sample time is in one of those shifts, but the problem is that I can have a lot of sample time and a lot of shifts.
Another example: My sample time: 11/11/2013 23:59:59. With my query I want to be able to know if it is in a shift in my database or not
Thanks and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: @EricZ Just to be sure you understand: SampleTime1, SampleTime2, SampleTime3. Shift1, Shift2, Shift3, Shift4.

Now, what I need to do, is to verify if the SampleTime1 is in the Shift1 or Shift2 or Shift3 or Shift4 and do the same thing with the SampleTime2 and so on. I only want to show the SampleTimes that are in a shift, I don't want to see the SampleTimes in none of the shifts in my shift table.

Is it more clear?

Again sorry I got difficulties explaining my problem in English, I'm doing my best and thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
`AND SampleTime between (Select min(ShiftStart) From @shifts) and (Select max(ShiftEnd) From @shifts)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you may want try this. P.S., I'm Canadian too :)

```
AND EXISTS (Select 1 From @shifts ss WHERE V.SampleTime BETWEEN ss.ShiftStart AND ss.ShiftEnd)
```